# Swift, error EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x100310448)

Tags: swift

This is the error code. If i delete the last "!" on imageData, i will get error also... how to fix it..

```
if let crew = user!["crew"] as? [String:Any], let crewQR = crew["crew_qrcode"] as? String {
        let imageUrlString = "http://52.221.231.3/gv/\(crewQR)"
        let imageUrl:URL = URL(string: imageUrlString)!
        //print(imageUrlString)
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {

            let imageData:NSData = NSData(contentsOf: imageUrl)!

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
                self.QRimg.image = image
                self.QRimg.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
                self.view.addSubview(self.QRimg)
            }
        }
    }
```

Error:
[image]

[After Edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erWiA.jpg)

Comment: `!` == forced unwrap == "I *want* the program to crash if something is nil"

Comment: Please include relevant code in the question itself, formatted as code and not a screenshot of it.

Comment: @Wan is this resolve?

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani not yet. just delete ( ! ) ? not really get the answer..can elaborate more?

Comment: Have you tried with `crewQR`?

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani ya i tried. still got error.

Comment: can you please paste here the `crewQR` url!

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani ok i uploaded the image (after edit) on the question

Comment: @WanJern use try-catch for after edit problem! See updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you get full URL of QR-Code from your Webservice so don't append the base address in the `imageUrlString` `crewQR` already a URL.

**Also, Try to safely unwrap the optional (`!`)**

```
let imageData:NSData = try? NSData(contentsOf: imageUrl)

if let imageData = imageData {
    let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a note, there is an obfuscated way this can happen, as I just found. I searched all my code for EVERY obvious force unwrapped value I could find and took care of all but the unavoidable ones.

Still happened.

The culprit happened to be a binding that was force unwrapping an optional like so

```swift
   
    //In ViewModel
    @Published var aFooThing: ABarThing? = nil
    
    //in a the ContentView
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel = ViewModel.instance
    ... 
    var body: some View {
        SomeViewCode()
            .sheet(isPresented: $showModal) {
                var boundFoo = Binding<ABarThing> = Binding(aFooThing)
                SomeModalViewBound(toFoo: boundFoo)

            }
            .onReceive(viewModel.$aFooThing) { thing in 
                self.showModal = thing != nil
            }
    }
```

The binding in this case unwraps the optional as per: [Binding init? documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding/init(_:)-5z9t9), however if the view holding that binding is still showing when the optional is again set to nil it breaks internally. I can't see this is currently documented anywhere.

I am assuming that when I set `aFooThing` back to nil, that when the view is animating away it tries to access the wrapped value while it disappears.